# ECS Fargate task throws 504 Gateway Time-out after some inactive time

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-copilot

i have a dockerized application that i have deployed on ECS using aws copilot.
Everything was working perfectly until I realized that after a while without requesting the service (something like 10 minutes) the next request throws 504 Gateway Time-out and after this request everything works normally again , someone have an idea maybe ? Can it be related to that i am still using free tier account on AWS ? Thanks for your help

Comment: It is not related to free tier. Free tier is just a billing construct. All it does is give you a discount when your bill is calculated. It sounds like your ECS container is having trouble processing a request after some idle time. You need to look into your ECS container logs to see if there was any error message related to that problem. Are you running anything else like AWS an Aurora Serverless database?

Comment: I have no logs error ... and no i am only connect to mongo cluster with mongoose